# How to compare day and time to current day and time using variable in php sql

Tags: php, mysql

i have 'user' table

```
id | name | day | time |
 1 | john |  6  |  11  |
```

i want to compare from coloumn 'day' and 'time' current day and time, am i doing something wrong here? all i know is that 6 is saturday from http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
$today = date("w");
$time = date("H");
$query = "SELECT name, day, time FROM `user`";
$result = mysql_query($query);  
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$a = $row['name'];
$b = $row['day'];
$c = $row['time'];

if($b == $today AND $c >= $time)
{
    echo 'success';
}
else
{
    echo "result 0";
}
```

but output is "result 0"

Comment: Did you run the code after 11am on a Saturday?

Comment: yes, in my country today is saturday 12.02 PM

Comment: Sorry... I meant before (need more coffee!).

Answer (score 0):

The code will only work if you run it between midnight (00:00) and 11:59 (am) on a Saturday. `H` format is 24-hour time.  Perhaps add the variables to the `echo` statements so you can see things like the computer does.

Answer (score 0):

When you Insert into database make sure you insert time with AM/PM so that you can compare correctly. 
date("h A"); //11 PM

Answer (score 0):

May be your PHP timezone configuration is different.
Try to get more detailed info, for example

```
echo "result 0, because $b != $today or $c < $time; my datetime is " . date('c');
```

Comment: it shows "result 0, because != 6 or < 19; my datetime is 2018-09-15T19:07:18+07:00" it didn't show the $b and $c

Comment: So problem is with SQL result. Try to add at the beginning of code:
`ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Also check your PHP version, mysql extension was removed in PHP 7.0.0 http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

I tried your php script with your data but it works fine for me.
May be your problem concerns timezone since *date()* returns current timezone like defined in the *date.timezone* parameter of php.ini. For instance, if you test your program at 12:00 and your UTC time is 2 or more hours below, the test will fail. To avoid this, either define your current TZ in php.ini or set the time zone directly on your php script using _date_default_timezone_set()_. The latter can be useful if users don't have the same TZ. You can store the TZ in the user table and get it to initialize properly in your script using _date_default_timezone()_

Comment: before, i try to "echo $time" it says 13, but when i try to use date_default_timezone_set it says 19 which is it's current time in my city. but it still error, and when i try to "echo $a / $b /$c" it didn't show anything

Answer (score 0):

you should try this if you want to get Indian time zone

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$ctime = date("h:i A ");

Comment: Please add a more general solution.